# how reliable is sending text messages from email

Tags: email, sms, sms-gateway, bulksms, mass-emails

How reliable is it to send text messages (sms) from an email client mail-to-sms gateway of a number?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

SMS in general are relatively reliable, I do know that they are not guaranteed with time though, and you could receive one hours later then it should have been... but sending to the sms gateway, does that make it more unreliable?

Please list sources, Your opinion and insight is insightful, but would prefer hard facts

I have been searching for some time, and can find much on the situation so I am assuming reliability is not an issue...

also another side question, knowing that I must know a individuals carrier to send a message any reason why I cannot spam the 'major' carriers and allow the messages to be bounced back at me to determine what carrier they have?

thank you!

Comment: "why I cannot spam the 'major' carriers" I think you answered your own question.